# Reading a column value from more than one table based on some condition - postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, view, pgadmin-4

I am trying to create a view for one of the tables I have. For one of the columns in the view, I am trying to read the value from the tables I have:

Table A:

```
id   b_id   c_id    d_id
1     1
2            1
3                     1
```

Table B:

```
id   code
1     64
```

Table C:

```
id    code
1     98
```

Table D:

```
id     code
1       26
```

In the above tables, A is my main table which has two foreign key references to tables B and C(b_id and c_id) respectively. And for each row in table A, only one of the two references (b_id or c_id) will be populated.

My task is to create a view for table A, say v_A, which will have the following columns:

View v_A:

```
code      code_table
64           B
98           C
26           D
```

In the above view, I have to first check for each row in table A, which of the foreign key references are populated, based on that I have to read the column 'code' and the column 'code_table' will have the name of the table I am populating the 'code' column.

I have been able to create simple views but this is a bit tricky for me. I was checking if I can use **case ...when** for the same but after a point that became a bit complicated too. I also can read the table name in postgres from the **information_schema** table. So I have bits and pieces of the solution but do not understand how to put it all together.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will work only when you have EITHER one table filled OR the OTHER - it does not solve conflict when both tales have matching keys:

```
t=# create view _a as select coalesce(b.code,c.code,d.code) code, case when b.id is not null then 'B' when c.id is not null then 'C' when d.id is not null then 'D' end from a
left outer join b on b.id = b_id
left outer join c on c.id = c_id
left outer join d on d.id = d_id;
CREATE VIEW
t=# select * from _a;
 code | case
------+------
   26 | D
   98 | C
   64 | B
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what if I have more than two tables to read from. For example, have 2 more foreign key references for 2 more tables ?

Comment: you drop the view and create another one - for more table to join

Comment: But your answer will only work if I have two two child tables. Have edited the question.

Comment: have edited answer - just add new table to the query. drop and create view. that's it